# Missing user and channel fields in google-benchmark conan package

Tags: conan, google-benchmark

I am trying to install the [google benchmark library](https://github.com/google/benchmark) using the C++ package manager Conan. However, the user and channel fields seem to be [missing from the conan-center](https://bintray.com/conan/conan-center/benchmark%3A_#files/_/benchmark/1.5.0/_/b2e44147e3c365a76d3d802a43758a63). I also get an error if I try to search for the library on the conan-center.

```
$conan search benchmark --remote=conan-center
ERROR: Value provided for user name, '_' (type str), is too short. Valid names must contain at least 2 characters.. [Remote: conan-center]
```

Is something off with the conan-center, or am I missing something? I noticed that other packages show the same behavior (gtest, doctest, etc.), although they also have a "regular" version provided by bincrafters.

Comment: Conan-center is using the latest conan client. user/channel was made optional, and if fact, all the packages generated with the new conan-center-index build service doesn't have a user/channel anymore. You probably need to upgrade to use it, what version of the client are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Conan [1.18](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/changelog.html#jul-2019) the package namespace became optional. This feature was introduced together with the new [Conan Center Index](https://blog.conan.io/2019/09/04/A-new-binary-building-service-for-Conan-center-packages.html) which has received all Conan recipes again, but without namespace.

All old and new packages, including from Conan Community and Bincrafters, will stay in Bintray Conan Center as well.

Now about your error:

> ERROR: Value provided for user name, '_' (type str), is too short. Valid names must contain at least 2 characters.. [Remote: conan-center]

This error occurred because your Conan client is outdated. I believe you are running <= 1.17.
I strongly recommend you update your Conan client to the latest version (1.20.4).

Regards!