# How do you reference a specific recipe revision from conan-index?

Tags: c++, conan, spdlog

I need to reference [spdlog 1.7.0 revision 1eebff2f51d90cb700b63c6d2449ebcb](https://conan.io/center/spdlog?version=1.7.0&revision=1eebff2f51d90cb700b63c6d2449ebcb&tab=recipe), not the latest revision, but I cannot seem to do this. Specifying revision requires the [user/channel#REV syntax](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/versioning/revisions.html), but recipes on conan index [doesn't seem to have user/channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59143781/missing-user-and-channel-fields-in-google-benchmark-conan-package).

How do I reference a specific revision from conan-index?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to install specific revision using command:

```
conan install spdlog/1.7.0@#1eebff2f51d90cb700b63c6d2449ebcb
```

Notice the `@` symbol after version.

Comment: This worked after I googled myself to doing export CONAN_REVISIONS_ENABLED=1. Before that I got "Revisions not enabled in the client".
Also, before exporting CONAN_REVISION_ENABLED=1, and I did conan install .. -s build_type=Debug --build missing, it silently still downloaded the latest revision.

Comment: If you are like me, you wildly copy-paste code from the internet only to later realize that the first occurence of `CONAN_REVISIONS_ENABLED` is plural whereas the second occurrence of `CONAN_REVISION_ENABLED` is singular. The correct one is in plural.

Comment: @JoakimThorén Oh no... Is it too late to apologize?